# What is Point constructor in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

What exactly does the Point constructor do? I am working on an image processing code and I could not find enough resources about it. My code is:

```
Mat element = getStructuringElement( morph_elem, Size( 2*morph_size + 1, 2*morph_size+1 ), Point( morph_size, morph_size ) );
```

`morp_size` is an integer value.

[Source page in OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dbe/tutorial_opening_closing_hats.html)

Can you explain to me?

Comment: it's not a function, it's the cv::Point constructor

Comment: @Miki thanks i changed

Comment: if you have to ask what a constructor is, you'd better read a good c++ book. However, you just make a cv::Point object with member variables x and y set to morph_size

Comment: Some explanation of the `cv::Point_<_Tp>` template, along with aliases below it. You'll find that `cv::Point` is an alias for `cv::Point2i` is an alias for `cv::Point_<int>` https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=point#Point_

Answer (score 0):

Point refers to the anchor position in the kernel i.e how the kernel is aligned with the source image. Point(-1,-1) would refer to the center of the kernel and is equivalent to kernelWidth/2 and kernelHeight/2.